# vb.net in-code line numbering tool?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for a tool (addon or something) for visual studio 2013 to add in-code line numbers for visual basic code (the ones to use with the "erl()" function).

I've been using mztools on vs2010, which is great, I have bought a license for 2010 but now I have to buy a new one to use in visual studio 2013 and I don't want to spend $75 (again) to use the line numbering tool and try-catch templates. Any alternative?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to use antique things like `On Error` and `Erl()`? All exceptions include a stack trace which usually contains the line numbers.

Comment: Yes. I don't want to depend on a PDB file. At least for now that we have a big application and it's working that way. And it would be only for Erl(); I won't use "On Error". Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the new caller information attributes that are available as of VS 2012?

Example taken from MSDN at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) page.

```
' Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices 
' Imports System.Diagnostics 

Private Sub DoProcessing()
    TraceMessage("Something happened.")
End Sub 

Public Sub TraceMessage(message As String,
        <CallerMemberName> Optional memberName As String = Nothing,
        <CallerFilePath> Optional sourcefilePath As String = Nothing,
        <CallerLineNumber()> Optional sourceLineNumber As Integer = 0)

    Trace.WriteLine("message: " & message)
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " & memberName)
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " & sourcefilePath)
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " & sourceLineNumber)
End Sub 

' Sample output: 
'   message: Something happened. 
'   member name: DoProcessing 
'   source file path: C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoVB\CallerInfoVB\Form1.vb 
'   source line number: 15
```

Comment: Thanks Chris; but I don't see how to use this within a try-catch block